# Turn off rendering component into DOM while running unit test

Tags: angular, karma-runner, karma-jasmine

I have recently learned to test angular component. I have used the following code using karma-jasmine-launcher in chrome

```
let fixture = TestBed.createComponent(AboutComponent);
let cut = fixture.componentInstance;
let element: Document = fixture.nativeElement;

// Run the changes
fixture.detectChanges();
let emailEle = element.querySelector('.email');

expect(emailEle.innerHTML).toEqual('email_test');
```

The above test works as expected but I see the AboutComponent rendering the HTML to DOM while running tests? Is this the way it works? For running unit tests, I would like to turn off DOM rendering? Can we turn off rendering elements into DOM? Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: you cant deactivate DOM rendering when testing the DOM interaction ( aka : let emailEle = element.querySelector('.email'); )       . If you want to test only internal logic, you can inject your component ( (at)Component extends (at)Injectable ) and do some logic unit test without instantiating the Component in the DOM ( the whole purpose à fixture )

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would argue that you *should* be rendering your DOM when testing your component; that's why it's not obvious how to *not* render the DOM. One thing I love about the new versions of Angular, over AngularJS, is how easy it is to render DOM.

BUT if there's some insane reason why you don't want to render the DOM in test, you basically just use the framework less. What I would do is "new" the component manually:

```ts
// first get your component dependencies
const myService = TestBed.get(MyService);
const someOtherDep = TestBed.get(SomeOtherDependency);

// next instantiate your component
const component = new AboutComponent(myService, someOtherDep);
```